# Xml variable substitution doesn't work with individual section key in web.config

Tags: asp.net, xml, azure, xml-parsing, devops

I am working with DevOps pipeline using yaml and has deployed a .net web application to cloud. I used xml variable substitution to replace a content from configSections in web.config file.

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Service Deploy'
  inputs:
    appType: webApp
    ConnectionType: AzureRM
    ConnectedServiceName: '***'
    ResourceGroupName: '***'
    WebAppName: '***'
    enableXmlVariableSubstitution: true
```

The web.config file contains multiple sections and a common key named "serviceurl" exist in both sections as below.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="roombooking" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="cabbooking" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <roombooking>
    <add key="serviceurl" value="localhost" />
  </roombooking>
  <cabbooking>
    <add key="serviceurl" value="localhost" />
  </cabbooking>
</configuration>
```

The application has deployed to multiple client locations. I have to replace "serviceurl" in web.config during deployment. The "serviceurl" is different for "roombooking" and "cabbooking". I tried xml  variable transformation during deployment as mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic) but it replaces both "serviceurl"'s into one value.

[image]

The web.config file after deployment as below.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="roombooking" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <section name="cabbooking" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <roombooking>
    <add key="serviceurl" value="http://example.com/" />
  </roombooking>
  <cabbooking>
    <add key="serviceurl" value="http://example.com/"/>
  </cabbooking>
</configuration>
```

I tried with different variable name like "roombooking.serviceurl", "roombooking--serviceurl" etc but nothing applied on individual section key. Is there any other way to apply xml variable substitution to replace "serviceurl" individually. Any help would be appreciated.